# Font question (MIT)

Tags: fonts

I'm not sure if I'm on the right forum for this. I've been a TeX user for awhile now, and I like to play around with different fonts. I was wondering what font they are using in the link below, and if this document was not typed in LaTeX (I'm not *completely* sure that it is), please refer me to another Exchange and I will delete this question.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-physics-ii-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2007/class-activities/chapter1fields.pdf

Comment: According to Adobe Reader's document properties info the main font is Times New Roman, but there is also a hint of Arial, Euclid Extra, MT-Extra and SymbolMT. Some math expressions look very odd, as though symbols (`=`) are missing and as though the kerning is off.

Comment: any pdf file your viewer or the pdffonts utility will list the included fonts

Comment: @moewe My Times looks quite different, or is it just me? Is it because I'm probably using a different package? See: https://imgur.com/BRo4oIO

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I will delete this then after I find out my last question.

Comment: The shapes of the letters look extremely similar. But your screenshot indeed looks a bit bolder and thicker to me than the document renders for me. Note that there are several Times New Roman variants and clones under different names, see for example https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Times_variants.png

Comment: @moewe Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Should I delete this question at this point?

Comment: @kylecampbell no need, the system handles closed duplicates quite gracefully